# How to customize master details page header in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am displaying a master details page.

Master page has the list of menu items and details page will have selected item details.

By default detail page is displaying title at left of the screen. **I want to customize details page title to show at center of page**.

**Is there anyway to customize details page title bar in Xamarin forms?**

Screenshots attached here[image: Master page]

[image]

Comment: Do you want the Title of the page centre aligned on android? Like in your case About should be center aligned?

Comment: Yes. That is correct. I want in both android and iOS

Comment: iOS by default has it center aligned and Android is a little complicated with this

Comment: Thank you for update. I just checked in iOS. Yes in iOS it is center aligned. 

Could you please suggest how can i make this for android?.. **Actually i even need to make some more changes like need to add my button in title bar, So if there is any way where i can make use of any custom view in details page title?**

Comment: Take a look at TitleView : https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/Navigation/TitleView/

Answer (score 5):

**Option 1**:

I think TitleView ([available since XF 3.2](https://blog.xamarin.com/xamarin-forms-3-2-0-released-going-big-with-little-things/)) is what you are looking for. All you have to do is create a the View you want to have as TitleView and asign it to the NavigationPage as:

***Code***

```
public class TitleViewPage : ContentPage
{
    public TitleViewPage()
    {
        var titleView = new Slider { HeightRequest = 44, WidthRequest = 300 };
        NavigationPage.SetTitleView(this, titleView);
        ...
    }
}
```

***XAML***

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="NavigationPageTitleView.TitleViewPage">
    <NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <Slider HeightRequest="44" WidthRequest="300" />
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>
    ...
</ContentPage>
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical#displaying-views-in-the-navigation-bar

**Option 2**:

Back in the days, before TitleView was available i used to simply remove navigation bar:

***Code***

```
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
```

***XAML***

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             ...
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">
```

And then i just put on top of my NavigationPage a StackLayout (my custom title bar) with all the icons/buttons/images/formatted text/etc that i wished.